# *ERROR: An exception of type FileNotFoundError occurred. Arguments: (2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using `subprocess.Popen` module from python 3.7 on windows 10 OS. Using this function I am trying to open the .hex file which is specified in the particular path. I have specified the path in this way...

```
iemHexPath = "C:\Haxiot_win_version\iem\hxc-iem-v00_23.hex"
```

This is the way I have mentioned in the python path. Now using `subprocess.Popen` I have done in this way,

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['st-flash', '--serial', mcuSTLinkSerial, '--format','ihex', 'write', iemHexPath], stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Even though I have that file in that specified path I'm getting the above mentioned File not found error. I have that particular code running successfully running on Raspberry pi environment. Now I'm porting the same code to windows, Could anyone suggest me any changes that would be great help.

NOTE: In the raspberry pi environment I had python 2.7 version upon running, now in windows it is 3.7 version. Does the change in the python version impact the this line of code. If so changes welcomed for python 3.7.

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the full traceback? If this error came from that line, it likely means that the system can't find the program "st-flash". You run the risk of currupting the path when you use backslashes in the string (e.g., `\t` is the tab character) but this one looks okay. Prepending the string as in `r"C:\Hax..."` solves that problem. But that's the same in 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: Is `st-flash` on the path? Have you tried providing a full path to the executable instead?

Comment: This is where I'm lagging I haven't tried providing full path for st-flash. I think I need to download this from ST website (this is something related to ST microcontroller)

Comment: Yes, you need to install the software. Your raspberry-pi is likely not running Windows so you'll need different utilities. And are you trying to flash something on the windows machine?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to flash the .hex file to ST microcontroller using python script. It was successful on raspberry pi now trying on windows

Comment: Should I add st-flash to the environmental variable path in windows?